# How to print day of the date in java without using inbuilt calendar date day packages

Tags: java

In this program I got all ordinary years day approximately.. 
example by giving input 1 1 2014 I get output as wednesday..
but not on leap year example by giving input 1 1 2000 i'm get exact answer saturday..
but I get answer for 1 1 2000 is monday.. can anyone solve this...

[Reference for Day of the date](http://easycalculation.com/funny/shortcuts/day.php)

```
//reference i made this program: http://easycalculation.com/funny/shortcuts/day.php
//gd = given date
//gm = given month
//gy = given year
//ym = year modulus (year % 100 to get last two digits)
//yp = year process (ym%4 to get remainder)
//wd = week days (0 for sunday, 1 for monday and so on...)
//d = day calculation (to get remainder from 0 to 6 .. which represents wd[0]
//for sunday so on)

import java.util.Scanner;
class dayof
{
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    int gd,gm,gy,ym,yp,d;
    int[] m=new int[]{0,3,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,0,3,5};
    String[] wd=new String[]{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date Month Year \"DD MM YYYY\"");
    gd=ip.nextInt();
    gm=ip.nextInt();
    gy=ip.nextInt();
    ym=gy%100;
    yp=ym%4;
    d=(gd+m[gm-1]+ym+yp+1)%7;
    System.out.print(wd[d]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `gd` as variable name, and having a comment explaining that `gd` means "given date", why not use `givenDate` as variable name? Readability is VERY important. Use long, meaningful variable names. And read SimpleDateFormat api documentation. This question is being asked twice a day.

Comment: issue is with leap year logic. If year is divisible by 4 or 400 it's a leap year except when it's only divisible by 100.

Comment: Why not to use existing libraries?

Comment: It was assessment task given by my guide.. and he told me don't use existing libraries..